# If one resistor is added to a circuit bypassing a longer parallel circuit, will the parallel circuit have current?

Tags: circuit-design, parallel, series

If you took and connected one bulb (the resistor in this case) to the end of a circuit in which the power wire bypasses the parallel circuit with multiple bulbs, would it cause the current to skip the parallel circuit?

Assume all 7 bulbs have the same resistance.

Of course, this one resistor probably cannot handle the power and might blow out quickly. However, aside from that.

See the illustration below:

[image]

Update: Here is another drawing of the same circuit (modified from the different drawing from the answerer below):

[image]

And here is what it would look like if the bypass was removed like the answerer's second picture:

[image]

Comment: If you had a water tank with a hole in it, water drips out. If it has two holes then water drips out through both.

Comment: @Andyaka, apparently the OP has decided that his assertion in the question is correct and doesn't care to hear anything contradicting that.

Comment: I untangled the lights to draw the circuit, someone else simplified my original drawing, then I added to it with the other bulb to ask this question.

Comment: Lookup "current divider formula"

Comment: "Electricity always takes  the shortest path" is a convenient way to explain some things to children. However, **it is not true**.

Answer (score 2):

Not quite. I don't know what the two boxes you made labeled "Power In" and "Power Out" are, but I'll assume they're of no significance.

The circuit you made is equivalent to:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fJjNGy.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

It should be clear now that you didn't actually bypass the other 6 bulbs. You just added one more parallel path for the current to flow through. Granted, that path will conduct more current than the other two, but it's not a bypass.

I think your drawing is confusing you because it visually *looks* like the last bulb on the right is bypassing the other 6. But since the red line *jumps over* the black line at the intersection, it is not a bypass. If you replaced that line jump with a node (and then removed the vertical segment directly below it), it would bypass as you originally stated.

[image]

Comment: Your circuit is a different circuit then the one I pictured.

Comment: @User91232, would you please elaborate why you think the circuit I drew is different than yours? Also, there will be no short if you read what I wrote. Mainly, the large blue letters that say "Remove this segment".

Comment: @User91232, just came across a similar question you asked yesterday, where the author of your accepted answer redrew your circuit in a similar manner as I did above. This new question just adds a small addition from yesterday's, so I'm curious why you're categorically rejecting the answer I've given.

Comment: I'm sorry, but the circuit in my answer is equivalent to yours. If the 6 lights are not turning on, it's probably because not enough current is flowing through those branches to illuminate the bulbs. That doesn't mean that zero current is flowing through them.

Comment: No I just redrew your circuit to be exactly like my circuit and updated my question with it. By the way, my circuit is not arbitrary. It is based on a string of Christmas lights. Also I was not saying that the 6 do not turn on. I was asking if they would or not. I'm trying to understand some fundamental circuit principles.

Comment: Ok, I see your new edit now. If you believe the new circuit you just made is equivalent to your original drawing, are you wrong. The original circuit does not have a bypass. The new one does. The circuits are not equivalent.

Comment: I see now that my revised drawing of your first picture is equal to your second picture (although not the first).

Comment: I revised it again to show both your first and your second picture.

Comment: Ok... so do you see now that in your update #1, all 7 resistors will get some amount of current and in update #2, only R7 will get current?

Comment: no not really I don't see that, if you could offer an explanation, that would help. Also are you still adamant that your drawing #1 is the same as my original drawing in the question? (both my original and update #1 are the same)

Comment: Also I thought it looked like it bypassed because it did NOT connect where the "bypass" is, not because I thought it did look like it connected. I was aware it does not connect at the bypass, and I'm asking if that will cause the power to skip the first bulbs. Also, are you saying that #3 will result in it skipping the 6?

Comment: The power will not skip the other 6 bulbs. The current has three distinct paths in your circuit. Path 1 is R1-3, path 2 is R4-6, and path 3 is R7 alone. Current will flow through all three paths (but not equally, as paths 1 and 2 have more total resistance).

Comment: ok but you should update your answer especially since your answer says that your first picture is the same when it isn't

Comment: Sorry, I did not see the edits you made to your comments and now my comment above is confusing. I just tried to move this discussion to chat, but I'm getting an error. In #3 schematic, yes, the 6 resistors will be skipped because both sides of the resistors are connected to the + terminal of the power source.

Comment: Your last comment was extremely helpful. Now I really understand all the diagrams. If you could just update your answer then I will accept it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47669/discussion-between-dan-laks-and-user91232).

Comment: No need to change my answer. I'm in the chat room if you want to discuss further.